# HI,Could you please help me resolving Issue while creating new column in Pyspark: I explained the issue as below:

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

query I'm using:

I want to replace existing columns with new values on condition, if value of another col = ABC then column remain same otherwise should give null or blank.
It's giving result as per logic but only for last column it encounters in loop.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

for i in df.columns:
    if i[4:]!='ff':        
        new_df=df.withColumn(i,F.when(df.col_ff=="abc",df[i])\
       .otherwise(None))

df:
+------+----+-----+-------+
| col1 |col2|col3 | col_ff|
+------+----+-----+-------+
|   a  | a  | d   | abc   |
|   a  | b  | c   | def   |
|   b  | c  | b   | abc   |
|   c  | d  | a   | def   |
+------+----+-----+-------+
```

required output:

```
+------+----+-----+-------+
| col1 |col2|col3 | col_ff|
+------+----+-----+-------+
|   a  | a  | d   | abc   |
| null |null|null | def   |
|   b  | c  | b   | abc   |
| null |null|null | def   |
+------+----+-----+-------+
```

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: You're overwriting `new_df` inside your loop each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you're overwriting `new_df` with the original DataFrame `df` in each iteration of the loop. You can fix it by first setting `new_df = df` outside of the loop, and then performing the `withColumn` operations on `new_df` inside the loop.

For example, if `df` were the following:

```python
df.show()
#+----+----+----+------+
#|col1|col2|col3|col_ff|
#+----+----+----+------+
#|   a|   a|   d|   abc|
#|   a|   b|   c|   def|
#|   b|   c|   b|   abc|
#|   c|   d|   a|   def|
#+----+----+----+------+
```

Change your code to:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

new_df = df
for i in df.columns:
    if i[4:]!='ff':        
        new_df = new_df.withColumn(i, F.when(F.col("col_ff")=="abc", F.col(i)))
```

Notice here that I removed the `.otherwise(None)` part because `when` will return `null` by default if the condition is not met.

You could also do the same using `functools.reduce`:

```python
from functools import reduce  # for python3
new_df = reduce(
    lambda df, i: df.withColumn(i, F.when(F.col("col_ff")=="abc", F.col(i))),
    [i for i in df.columns if i[4:] != "ff"], 
    df
)
```

In both cases the result is the same:

```python
new_df.show()
#+----+----+----+------+
#|col1|col2|col3|col_ff|
#+----+----+----+------+
#|   a|   a|   d|   abc|
#|null|null|null|   def|
#|   b|   c|   b|   abc|
#|null|null|null|   def|
#+----+----+----+------+
```